# Optimising alogorithm for converting a long long int (e.g=12345678) to new long long int of this type (123456787654321) means reverse of it has added

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I want to optimize the algorithm for converting a long long int (e.g=12345678)  to a new long long int of this type (12345678**7654321**) means the reverse of it has added.
My current algorithm and function to do it is as;

```
long long ans_int(long long n){
    long long temp=n;
    n=n/10;
    while(n>0){
        long long reminder=n%10;
        temp=temp*10+reminder;
        n=n/10;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I also tried the string approach but it's slower than the above approach. Can it be done using bit manipulation? Looking for a bit manipulation approach. I have very little knowledge about bit manipulation.

```
long long ans_int(long long n){
    string r=to_string(n);
    string t=r;
    for(int i=r.length()-2;i>=0;i--){
        t=t+r[i];
    }
    return stoi(t);
}
```

How can I do it in the fastest possible way?

Comment: What's the question you are trying to solve?  These rearrange digits questions are usually very easy if you treat them as a string of digits and not an integer.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Though that just hides the math in whatever functions you call to convert to and from a decimal string.  But the system's functions for doing this are probably more efficient than yours.

Comment: If you were doing it more than once you could, for example, create a lookup table for, say, 5 digits at a time. Then process the value in 5 digit chunks.

Comment: @NateEldredge But if you are reading in the inputs and read as std::string - no conversion necessary.  These quiz questions usually start with read an integer - just to start you off on the wrong track.

Comment: I don't think there is a *bit-manipulation* solution. As 10 is not a power of 2 you cannot really use bit-operations to manipulate the decimal representation of your number.

Comment: Where do you get the input number from?

Comment: @EOF it's a subpart of the competitive programming CodeChef platform which involves this and exponential modular operation, I have already highly optimized the modular part, so only this can be optimized. ps: I was getting time limit errors.

Comment: @rajakr Which codechef problem?

Comment: You might be able to get a little faster (you have to measure) by using a modulo 100 and a lookup table (going two digits at a time, instead of one.)

Comment: The `to_string` function might be faster than doing divisions in a loop, but it's probably not a huge improvement. The rest of the code in the second snippet is definitely not an improvement.  You can try combining the two snippets. Use `to_string` to get the array of digits, and use the multiply/add from the first snippet to compute the answer.

Comment: Time limit exceeded is often not about optimization at all, it's about whether you chose the exact algorithm the question expects or not.